# Restoring page (back button) with sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, css, back-button, session-storage, web-storage

I am using session storage to save link content and image. It work but problem is with back button. It doesn't work. It might resolve History API but support is horrible. No IE, Android support...Is there an alternative? With sessionStorage i can not resolve it? Here is code:

**My links**

```
      <li><a data-tab="#home" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a data-tab="#link1" href="#football">Football</a></li>
      <li><a data-tab="#link2" href="#hockey">Hockey</a></li>
      <li><a data-tab="#link3" href="#">Tennis</a></li>
      <li><a data-tab="#link4" href="#">Basketball</a></li>
      <li><a data-tab="#link5" href="#">Baseball</a></li>
```

**And JS (sessionStorage)**

```
$("#navigation a").on("click", function(e){
      var currTab = $(this).data("tab"),
          bodyClassName = "bg-" + currTab.replace(/#/, "");
      sessionStorage.setItem("currentTab", currTab);
      sessionStorage.setItem("bodyClassName", bodyClassName);
      $(".panel").hide();
      $(currTab).fadeIn();

      document.body.className = bodyClassName;
    });

    var lastSelectedTab = sessionStorage.getItem("currentTab"),
        lastBodyClassName = sessionStorage.getItem("bodyClassName");

    if (!lastSelectedTab) {
      lastSelectedTab = "#home";
      lastBodyClassName = "bg-home"
    }
    $(lastSelectedTab).fadeIn();
    document.body.className = lastBodyClassName;
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at **[this article](http://www.accessadvertising.co.uk/think/html5-history-api-making-history-ajax-part-ii)**, it'll probably help you a lot!

#### Updated

I've created this sample and it works with browser history for me (tested in Google Chrome).

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#navigation a").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var currTab = $(this).data("tab");
        $(".panel").hide();
        $(currTab).fadeIn();
    sessionStorage.setItem("currentTab", currTab);
    });

    var currTab = sessionStorage.getItem("currentTab");
    $(".panel").hide();
    $(currTab).fadeIn();
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
div {
   width: 700px;
   height: 500px;
   border: 10px solid #000;
}

div#home { background-color: green; }
div#link1 { background-color: lime; }
div#link2 { background-color: red; }
div#link3 { background-color: blue; }
div#link4 { background-color: yellow; }
div#link5 { background-color: white; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://www.google.com.br" />Go to google</a>
<ul id="navigation">
      <li><a data-tab="#home" href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a data-tab="#link1" href="/">Football</a></li>
      <li><a data-tab="#link2" href="/">Hockey</a></li>
      <li><a data-tab="#link3" href="/">Tennis</a></li>
      <li><a data-tab="#link4" href="/">Basketball</a></li>
      <li><a data-tab="#link5" href="/">Baseball</a></li>
</ul> 

<div class="panel" id="home"></div>
<div class="panel" id="link1"></div>
<div class="panel" id="link2"></div>
<div class="panel" id="link3"></div>
<div class="panel" id="link4"></div>
<div class="panel" id="link5"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so historyAPI is probably the only opinion how to fix back button?

Comment: where are you putting this JS?

Comment: Is the `sessionStorage` the best approach to restore some parameters when navigation bavck in Angular?